# when does bluebird log unhandled rejections?

Tags: promise, bluebird

I'm having trouble understanding when bluebird will log an unhandled rejection versus dropping it.  I guess this has something to do with what the documentation calls "the second turn" but I'm not clear what that means.

```
Promise.reject(new Error("oops"))
```

-> no log

```
Promise.reject(new Error("oops")).then(function() {})
```

-> stack trace logged

```
Promise.method(function() { throw new Error("oops"); })()
```

-> no log

```
Promise.method(function() { throw new Error("oops"); })().then(function() {})
```

-> stack trace logged

```
Promise.promisify(function(k) { k(new Error("oops"), null); })()
```

-> stack trace logged

I am in the middle of converting some code to bluebird promises and I am getting rejections dropped all over the place.  (Okay, first it was [#100](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/100), I'm an idiot.) I guess I will use .promisify rather than .method to get past my current silent failures but I'm frightened that there might be other circumstances where I'll miss a thrown error.

Comment: This is regression bug since changing the unhandled rejection architecture in 1.0.4, can you file an issue?

Comment: just use `done` instead of `then` and get over it ;-)

Comment: In my application, these are reusable functions, so I don't know whether we are done. Besides, it's scary to have exceptions just dropped for any reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unhandled rejections should be logged whenever there's an unhandled rejection, so 1 and 3 are bugs because you don't have any handlers for the rejection registered by the "start of the second turn".

Comment: Thanks - I see this is fixed in 1.0.6.